# Cascade transactional Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have the following code:

```
@Transactional
public void methodA{
  actionA;
}

@Transactional
public void methodB{
  actionB;
}
```

How would I solve the problem cascades transactions in the following method methodC in case of method methodB throw an exception?

```
public void methodC{
methodA;
methodB;
}
```

I am currently using spring

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be if you called

```
@Transactional
public void methodA {
   actionA;
   methodB;
}

@Transactional
public void methodB {
   actionB;
}
```

Comment: with this solution the method "methodA" isn't elementary

Answer (score 0):

"How would I solve the problem cascades transactions in the following method methodC in case of method methodB throw an exception?"  <-- I don't totally get this statement. 
However if you want to solve the cascades transactions exception, you better catch the exception when it actually happens in case of methodB failure.

```
   public void methodC{
        methodA;
        try{
            methodB; 
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
     }
```

Comment: in method "methodC" I like to do rollback when the method "methodB" throw an exception